# Using the extensionAttributes in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, user-object

So I'm working on expanding the data stored about User Objects in an Active Directory, but we are looking for possible candidates to store the data in, as a lot of the fields have already been used.

We found the fields 'extensionAttribute(1-15)' and looked online for some information about them.

I couldn't find a lot of information about them. What I found was they are a result of implementing Exchange to your system.

> Are they suited for adding extra data to an User Object?
>
> Will they not be removed at a point?
>
> Can I find some more documentation about them somewhere?
>
> Won't they be affected when we may want to implement other systems in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use those for anything you want. We use several of them in our organization. For example, we use extensionAttribute6 as a fourth level in our organizational information that shows up in the Global Address List in Outlook. (after company, department and physicalDeliveryOfficeName).

We use a couple of the other ones for other things.

You're right that it's the Exchange prep that creates those attributes. They're there to use. But be aware that deleting a mailbox can clear those values: http://setspn.blogspot.ca/2010/10/avoiding-ad-schema-extension.html

Comment: Is deleting a mailbox the only possible of their values being cleared?

And is that the only downside of using them?

Comment: There is no other downside I'm aware of. I've never seen them cleared in normal operation.